# Odata query to select empty arrays on expand?

Tags: arrays, filter, syntax, odata

I am clearly new to OData querying and could use some guidance. I am hoping to use $filter to filter out results and I can't seem to find a good resource for syntax. I am using Odata to select table A, expand on navigation propertyB and count all of occurrences where B is 1) an empty array, 2) has a count of 1 object or 3) has a count of greater than 1 objects.  Here is an example of where I want to expand on propertyB. Any help, constructive criticism is greatly appreciated!

`http://{{baseUrl}}/odata/tableA?&$top=50&$count=true&$expand=propertyB`

Now, I am trying to use the filter function to filter out only the data that has propertyB as an empty array.

```
          {
            "myNumber": "00000056218",
            "actionType": null,
            "numberXTimes": [],
            "propertyB": []

          }
```

Here is an example where I would like to have values returned that show "propertyB" has one object:

```
http://{{baseUrl}}/odata/tableA?&$top=50&$expand=propertyB&$filter=contains(propertyB/myNumber, (myNumber.Length ==1))&$count=true

         {
            "myNumber": "00000056218",
            "actionType": null,
            "numberXTimes": [],
            "propertyB": [
                     {
                    "myNumber": "00000056218",
                    "desiredId": 300387799,

                }
             ]

          }
```

Unfortunately, my querys aren't working. I would love your help to figure this out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an exact solution for you, but I can provide a couple of workarounds.

First, you could use [`$count` on your `expand` parameter](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part1-protocol.html#_Toc31358955) to get the count of elements present in `propertyB`. This would look something like:

```
http://{{baseUrl}}/odata/tableA?&$top=50&$count=true&$expand=propertyB($count=true)
```

the response would be:

```
{
  "myNumber": "00000056218",
  "actionType": null,
  "numberXTimes": [],
  "propertyB@odata.count": 1,
  "propertyB": [
    {
      "myNumber": "00000056218",
      "desiredId": 300387799
    }
  ]
}
```

But with this, you are just getting the count and are not actually filtering the results.

As an alternative, you could use the [`any()` lambda function of OData](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_any) to get only those entries for which `propertyB` is **not empty**, and filter out rest.

```
http://{{baseUrl}}/odata/tableA?&$top=50&$count=true&$expand=propertyB&$filter=propertyB/any()
```

I hope these workarounds work for your situation.